# Have zookeeper sequential number continuous since 3.4.x?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

In my project, I need the latest sequential number without get children nodes, because there are too many children nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Acording to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338076/zookeeper-persistent-sequential-incrementing-by-two) and confirmed by my experiments, since Zookeeper 3.4 the sequential znodes are numbered from the parent's `PersistedStat.cversion` number, that stores the number of znodes created under it. You can calculate this number querying the parent znode stat and then applying the following formula:

`PersistedStat.cversion = (ZnodeStat.cversion + ZnodeStat.numChildren) /2`

That way, you don't need to use `get_children()` to discover the number of the last created znode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. 
What you could to is watch the node that is n+1 (which doesn't exist) and then take action when it triggers a watch upon creation.

Also consider leader election where that node publishes itself. This can cause big blasts of data to go out though if you have a lot of nodes.
http://techblog.outbrain.com/2011/07/leader-election-with-zookeeper/